# Is network bytes measured per second or per minute in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

What is the measured period of time for the bandwidth metrics of [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)? Is it bytes per second or bytes per minute?

This is sample output of Prometheus:

```
# HELP node_network_receive_bytes bytes receive from /proc/net/dev.
# TYPE node_network_receive_bytes gauge
node_network_receive_bytes{device="eth0"} 1.23456789e+09
```

Answer (score 2):

Those come from the kernel, they are since the device was created.

To convert to a per-second value you can use the `rate` function:

```
rate(node_network_receive_bytes[1m])
```

Comment: OK, understand, it is the absolute number of bytes transferred since the device was created.